# Why does Html img tag only allow a maximum of 6 src to the same host?

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am trying to request 10 streams from the same host using img tag but it can only go to a maximum of six, but if I combine ip addresses with hostnames it does work.

Below is the html I use.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1> Streams </h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let idx of streams" class="col-md-3">
        <img [src]="idx" alt="">
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Working solution:**
If I combine ip addresses with hostnames it works.

```
 streams = [
    'http://jetson1.local:8085/api/stream/accc8ee8f2c5',
    'http://jetson1.local:8085/api/stream/bcad28d47b1c',
    'http://jetson1.local:8085/api/stream/4447cc9d2a8714',
    'http://jetson1.local:8085/api/stream/0013e2fa6841',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/48ea63a53318',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/0013e2fa67dc',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/08eded8744a1',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/9c14633240be',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/5804cb009268',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/38af290fc271'
  ];
```

**These don't work.**
If I define it like below it does not work.

```
 streams = [
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/accc8ee8f2c5',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/bcad28d47b1c',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/4447cc9d2a8714',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/0013e2fa6841',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/48ea63a53318',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/0013e2fa67dc',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/08eded8744a1',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/9c14633240be',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/5804cb009268',
    'http://192.168.51.76:8085/api/stream/38af290fc271'
  ];
```

Is it some sort of limitation based on the browser. I tried both on firefox and chrome. If so, how can one overcome this?

It just shows pending.

[image]

Comment: Can you quantify "Doesn't work" mean? Do the images ever load?  I thought browsers limited their number of simultaneous network requests for various performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `img` tag. The browsers themselves limit the number of connections they maintain to any given domain to somewhere between 2 and 15 (all modern browsers use 6).

> If so, how can one overcome this?

"Don't do it" would be the best solution.

Alternatively you can serve from multiple subdomains, but then you risk hitting the *global* connections limit (between 10 and 20 on modern browsers). An other mitigation technique is to use HTTP/2, such that multiple requests can be *multiplexed* on a single connection. The final alternative would be to use websocket instead of more naive streams, websocket has a much higher connection limit than HTTP (200+, though chrome used to have a much lower limit of 30 / host)